# Quantities of Minimization in Least-Squares Lines

Tags: linear-algebra

One of the simplest forms of linear regression is to find a best fit line to the points $(x_i,y_i)$, for $i=1$ to $n$. The least-squares line, $y=\beta_0+\beta_1x$, minimizes the sum of squares of residuals in $y$, namely
$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (\beta_0+\beta_1x_i-y_i)^2$.

Question:
Does this least-squares line, $y=\beta_0+\beta_1x$, also minimize the sum of squares of residuals in $x$, namely
$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n ( (y_i-\beta_0)/\beta_1-x_i)^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the two objective functions you are considering are different, the minimum cannot be the same. So, my answer is **no**.

Let us try with five data points defined by $x_i=i$ and $y_i=2 x_i+3+\frac{(-1)^i}{2}$ and compute. The first objective function is $$F=\sum\limits_{i=1}^5 (a+bx_i-y_i)^2=\left(a+b-\frac{9}{2}\right)^2+\left(a+2 b-\frac{15}{2}\right)^2+\left(a+3
   b-\frac{17}{2}\right)^2+\left(a+4 b-\frac{23}{2}\right)^2+\left(a+5
   b-\frac{25}{2}\right)^2$$ The second objective function is $$G=\sum\limits_{i=1}^5 ( (y_i-a)/b-x_i)^2=\left(\frac{\frac{9}{2}-a}{b}-1\right)^2+\left(\frac{\frac{15}{2}-a}{b}-2\right)^2+\left(\frac{\frac{17}{2}-a}{b}-3\right)^2+\left(\frac{\frac{23}{2}-a}{b}-4\right)^2+
   \left(\frac{\frac{25}{2}-a}{b}-5\right)^2$$ Now, consider the partial derivatives; after expansion and simplifications they write $$F'_a=10 a+30 b-89$$ $$F'_b=30 a+110 b-307$$ $$G'_a=\frac{10 a+30 b-89}{b^2}$$ $$G'_b=\frac{-4 a (5 a+15 b-89)+614 b-1749}{2 b^3}$$ Since these partial will be forced to be zero we can remove the denominators and  you can then notice  that $F'_a=G'_a$ but $F'_b \neq G'_b$ (moreover, notice that $G'_b$ is not a linear equation  since $a^2$ and $ab$ terms appear in it).

Now, solving, the minimum of $F$ corresponds to $a=2.90$, $b=2.00$ while the minimum of $G$ corresponds to $a=2.72$, $b=2.06$.

You could easily repeat all of that using Excel solver.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. I tried with some data as well, and I reached the same conclusion as you. However, in your proof, the condition $F'_b \neq G'_b$ is not sufficient to prove the conclusion, right? $F$ and $G$ are functions of two variables $a$ and $b$, and we need to find $a$ and $b$ at the minimum of these two functions.

Comment: For getting the minimum, we solve $F'_a=F'_b=0$ and $G'_a=G'_b=0$. Since $F'_a=G'_a$ but $F'_b\neq G'_b$, the solutions cannot be the same.

Comment: Thanks Claude Leibovici for your reply. Here's a possible counterexample. $F(a,b)=b^2$, and $G(a,b)=b^4$. Then $F'_a(a,b)=G'_a(a,b)=0$ identically, and $F'_b(a,b)=2b \neq G'_b(a,b)=4b^3$. The minimum of $F$ and $G$ are the same - the entire line $b=0$.